# How to prove size of a list in Leon?

Tags: scala, leon

I am trying to prove that the size (number of elements) in a list is non-negative, but Leon fails to prove it---it just times out. Is Leon really not capable of proving this property, or am I using it wrongly? My starting point is a function I read in the paper "An Overview of the Leon Verification System".

```
import leon.lang._
import leon.annotation._

object ListSize {
  sealed abstract class List
  case class Cons(head: Int, tail: List) extends List
  case object Nil extends List

  def size(l: List) : Int = (l match {
    case Nil => 0
    case Cons(_, t) => 1 + size(t)
  }) ensuring(_ >= 0)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Previous versions of Leon treated Scala's `Int` type as mathematical, unbounded, integers. The most recent versions treat values of `Int` as signed 32-bit vectors, and require the use of `BigInt` to represent unbounded integers.

In the provided example, Leon times out attempting to build a list of size `Int.MaxValue`, a counter-example which would demonstrate that the postcondition does not hold for bounded integers.

If you change the return type of `size` to `BigInt`, the program verifies as expected.

Comment: But why don't I get a counter-example to tbe program with Int?

Comment: Leon searches for counter-examples by (conceptually) enumerating structures of increasing size. The smallest counter-example to this verification condition has size `Int.MaxValue`, so it'll take some time to get there (and you'll run out of memory before).

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are all right, but do not help us if we wish to use Int instead of BigInt and have a sense that the size of reasonable lists is non-negative. The following simple trick takes care of that and works in stainless:

```
def listLength(l: List[T]): Int = {
    l match {
        case head :: tl => {
            val tlLen = listLength(tl)
            if(tlLen < Int.MaxValue) {
                tlLen + 1
            } else {
                0
            }
        }
        case Nil() => 0
    }
} ensuring(0 <= _)
```

See, for example, https://github.com/epfl-lara/bolts/blob/master/data-structures/seqs/ArrayList.scala in the bolts repository of https://stainless.epfl.ch/